# How to display accuracy for all 10 CIFAR10 classes in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm a new ML programmer and working on a code to display accuracy for all classes. The code only shows the most likely class.

And also, I put a print a the results variable to see what was in there, is it normal that everything is 0 except one class? should be some kind of weights and probability for all classes?

the whole project is about transfer learning, I am using VGG16 in keras and cifar10, the model_weights.h5  has the features extracted from cifar10 and the model_structure file is a JSON file with the structure of the model, the vgg16 with the dense layers modified

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
from pathlib import Path
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

# These are the CIFAR10 class labels from the training data (in order from 0 to 9)
class_labels = [
    "Plane",
    "Car",
    "Bird",
    "Cat",
    "Deer",
    "Dog",
    "Frog",
    "Horse",
    "Boat",
    "Truck"
]

# Load the json file that contains the model's structure
f = Path("model_structure.json")
model_structure = f.read_text()

# Recreate the Keras model object from the json data
model = model_from_json(model_structure)

# Re-load the model's trained weights
model.load_weights("model_weights.h5")

# Load an image file to test, resizing it to 32x32 pixels (as required by this model)
img = image.load_img("catdog11.jpg", target_size=(32, 32))

# Convert the image to a numpy array
image_to_test = image.img_to_array(img)

# Add a fourth dimension to the image (since Keras expects a list of images, not a single image)
list_of_images = np.expand_dims(image_to_test, axis=0)

# Make a prediction using the model
results = model.predict(list_of_images)
print("what is in results?: ", results)

# Since we are only testing one image, we only need to check the first result
single_result = results[0]

# We will get a likelihood score for all 10 possible classes. Find out which class had the highest score.


most_likely_class_index = int(np.argmax(single_result))
class_likelihood = single_result[most_likely_class_index]


# Get the name of the most likely class
class_label = class_labels[most_likely_class_index]

# Print the result
print("This is image is a {} - Likelihood: {:2f}".format(class_label, class_likelihood))
```

this is what is displaying at the moment

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2019-04-15 17:56:05.082617: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] 
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
```

what is in results?:  [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

This is image is a Dog - Likelihood: 1.000000

Process finished with exit code 0

---

**THE RESULT I WANT TO ACHIEVE is:**

CIFAR 10 has 10 classes, so when I input an image, it should appear for example:

frog: 0.4%

truck: 0.002%

and so on

Comment: Since the output layer uses a softmax function all the class probabilities will sum upto to 1. You can convert the probabilities to percentages as you wish.

Comment: but I just cannot realize how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the last output line which will multiply the `class_likelihood` into percentage :

```
print("This is image is a {} - Likelihood: {}".format(class_label, class_likelihood*100 ) )
```

In short, you just need to multiply `class_likelihood` by 100.

```
percent = class_likelihood * 100
```